# IE7 DIV does not stretch with content inside it

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with IE7. In IE6, Firefox and other browsers, the DIV containing the content stretches vertically depending on how much content is in it. In IE7 however, the DIV only stretches to the absolute minimum height of the page then it stops... it even cuts off the content inside of it.

I cannot figure out for the life of me why this is happening.

The DIV is .content and the example can be found here: http://beta.beanersfuncuts.com/?page=products. It also does this on other pages too with content too long.

I will continue looking for the source of the problem, but any extra help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you use quirks-mode or standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have placed the `content` div inside the `top_menu` div. The content will extend outside the div, but in IE7 it will not affect the size of the table.

Removing the height specification on the `top_menu` div will make all the content visible in IE7, but that might have some unwanted side effects... You should mode the content out of the menu.

Comment: Thank you, Guffa!

I can't believe that had happened, I did not realize that my content div was inside the top_menu div. I simply closed the top_menu div and everything works perfectly now! I guess I just needed a fresh set of eyes to look at it.

Thank you again! (And sorry for the late response)

Answer (score 1):

This might be the same issue, along with tweaks (a couple iterations, so scan the whole thread) to achieve the result you want:

[Div Height:100% Messes Up In IE 7](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic38765.htm)